# I can't enable the mic on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, bluetooth, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

[image]

I'm experiencing a persistent issue on my Ubuntu system where the audio driver gets disabled after each shutdown or restart. To resolve this, I have to reinstall the audio driver via the terminal. This problem affects both wired and Bluetooth microphones.

Here are the steps I've taken:

Install bluez:

```
sudo apt-get install bluez
```

List Connected Bluetooth Devices:

```
bluetoothctl
```

Install pavucontrol:

```
sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
```

Check Input Devices in pavucontrol:

```
pavucontrol
```

Despite these efforts, the issue persists, and I have also tried PulseAudio and PipeWire without success. I can hear audio output, but the microphone is not functioning.

I'm seeking a permanent solution to this problem. Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you check whether there is an option `Handsfree - Rockerz 425` on output devices? If yes, switch to that option and check your input device.

Comment: I barely see the audio slider option. I think I may accidently remove some inbuild audio services .